# How to download sql database (apache server) to local using terminal?

Tags: mysql, terminal

I'm looking for downloading my sql database from a remote server to my local machine.

I used scp command like that :

```
scp -r user@ip:/var/lib/mysql/mydatabase .
```

It works, but I have lot of files (related to tables in my DB I suppose) : db.opt, files in .frm, .MYD, and .MYI

I tryed to copy my files to a new database folder in MAMP (to test the db), but when I watch my db in PhpMyAdmin I can see only one table :/

Is there a better way to download directly a sql database from server to local with terminal ?

Thanks a lot for your help guys

Comment: Dump the db tables, `tar.gz` them and then `scp`...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use command, mysqldump --all-databases.

Over ssh work like this:

```
ssh user@ip mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql
```

Download the dump with scp, and restore it whit php-myadmin.

Answer (score 0):

simply use the mysqldump command over ssh, and redirect the output, so, you will have a dump of the DB

something like

```
ssh user@ip 'mysqldump -u dbuser -pdbassword database_name' > database_dump.sql
```

The you can restore the database using mysql on your local machine:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword db_name < database_dump.sql
```

If the database is big, you can pipe a gzip like below:

```
ssh user@ip 'mysqldump -u dbuser -pdbassword database_name | gzip ' > database_dump.sql.gz
```

to restore on your local machine

```
gzip -dc database_dump.sql.gz | mysql -uusername -ppassword
```

Comment: Ok I see.
So when you say restore the database to my local machine using
   mysql -uusername -ppassword db_name < database_dump.sql
The database will be download on my local machine like scp command ?
Do I can delete the dump after downloading the db ?

Comment: The first command (the ssh one) is to download the dump on your PC. The restore, is to restore the backup from your PC. After restoring the backup, yes, you can delete the local copy

Comment: I have a permission denied :/

Comment: It could be that simply you are trying to write in a directory where you don't have permissions